# How to integrate client side validation with RoR 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can see client_side_validations gem is no longer maintained, how do I set about validating a Rails 4 form on the client?

Thanks

Comment: What sort of validation? Please be more specific

Comment: Just looking at form validation at this stage (min length, email). In .Net/MVC I've sometime had a quirky validation requirement that requires validating several fields at once (knockoutjs/computed observables) - so trying to see if railists hand roll this stuff or include a gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client side validation is quirky as it is tightly coupled to the backend framework and the two aren't necessarily in sync with subsequent updates. In my experience with .NET / MVC 3, client side libraries break when you upgrade to the latest jQuery and you don't get much control on how it behaves with different browsers. My recommendation is to use HTML5 validation as it degrades very gracefully with older browsers.

You may also write some javascript code. The best course is to keep it simple since you always get to rely on the backend to make sure everything is valid. The idea here is to enhance the experience not hinder it.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Parsely js](http://parsleyjs.org/). They have nice api. You can add it in the form of gem also [parsely-rails](https://github.com/mekishizufu/parsley-rails)